# QT c++ "Windows.h no such a file or dictionary in main.ccp"

Tags: c++, qt

My Qt c++ cross platform game work with windows but when it comes to the Linux there is an error "`Windows.h` no such a file or dictionary in `main.ccp`".

Comment: `Windows.h` is, unsurprisingly, a Windows-only header file. It doesn't exist on Linux. You'll need to find a Linux-compatible way of doing whatever you're trying to do (or seeing as you're already using QT, a cross-platform way).

Comment: `no such a file or dictionary` are you sure it isn't `no such file or directory`?

Comment: Since you're using Qt, why are you including `Windows.h` to begin with? Is there something from that header that you actually need?

Comment: "Windows.h" "cross platform" pick zero or one of the above.

Answer (score 0):

How would you expect `windows.h` to exist on a nom-Windows OS? On Linux you're supposed to have `qt.h` or so (and change those library function calls to Qt ones, instead of WinAPI).

`windows.h` is available only on Windows XP or newer (and Windows 2000 Professional). You can only choose one option: *cross-platform* or *Windows*.

I also doubt your program is right, since `main.ccp` is not a valid name for a C++ source file.